# sort vector by using lambda with &&

Tags: c++

I am trying to sort a vector elements by using lambda but I have a question. I am trying to sort it base on 2 values from a struct but lambda does not allow me to do it like that.

Here is what i am trying to do:

```
struct Test
{   int Current;
    int Max;
};

std::vector<Test*> VectorA

std::sort(VectorA.begin(), VectorA.end(), [](Test& test, Test& test2) {return (test.Current > test2.Current) && (test.Max > test2.Current); });
```

Is it possible to use it like that ?

Comment: Your vector contains `Test*`, not `Test` as your lambda implies.

Comment: Why does your lambda take non-const references as inputs? Do you intend to modify them? (Hopefully not)

Comment: Your comparaison doesn't comply with [strict weak ordering](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Compare) neither.

Comment: thanks for telling me my mistakes i learned from it i am grateful for that i just started to learning c++

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `std::vector` contains elements of type `Test*`, not `Test`.
Therefore your lambda should accept references to `Test*` objects, and dereference the pointers with `operator->`.

Since you do not need to modify these objects, it is better for your lambda to accept the arguments by a `const` reference.

A complete example:

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

struct Test
{
    int Current;
    int Max;
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<Test*> VectorA;
    std::sort(VectorA.begin(), 
              VectorA.end(),
//---------------vvvvv--------------vvvvv--------------
              [](Test* const& test, Test* const& test2)
//----------------------------vv---------------vv-----------
                { return (test->Current > test2->Current) && (test->Max > test2->Current); });
    return 0;
}
```

---

**Edit:** my answer above addressed only the issue of the c++ syntax itself.

As commented [below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74337618/sort-vector-by-using-lambda-with/74337669#comment131236747_74337669) by @Jarod42, there is also a semantic issue here - your comparison logic does not comply with strict weak ordering (see: [Wikipedia - Weak Ordering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_ordering)).

Comment: Comparer is wrong too about strict weak ordering, maybe `return std::tie(lhs.Current, lhs.Max) > std::tie(rhs.Current, rhs.Max);`

Comment: @Jarod42 good point. I merely addressed the syntax issue. Updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks guys for helping me and thanks for explain and telling me my mistakes i am grateful for that